# How to create text come one by one and go back to fix the spelling

Tags: javascript, css, animation, textbox, slideshow

I have inserted a text inside the placeholder.And it's working properly.Now After appearing the text, I want the cursor to go to a specific point(here doubts) and correct the misspelled word(doubts to doubt).

How to do it ? Can you show me any example I want to do in the project.

#### Code###

```js
var txt = "Please write your message.If any doubts, don't hesitate to make a questions !";
var timeOut;
var txtLen = txt.length;
var char = 0;
$('textarea').attr('placeholder', '|');
(function typeIt() {
  var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (200 - 30)) + 30;
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
    char++;
    var type = txt.substring(0, char);
    $('textarea').attr('placeholder', type + '|');
    typeIt();

    if (char == txtLen) {
      $('textarea').attr('placeholder', $('textarea').attr('placeholder').slice(0, -1)) // remove the '|'
      clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }

  }, humanize);
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <textarea cols="50" rows="15" placeholder=""></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Here is the link in codepen
http://codepen.io/jahid-webdev/pen/pgggXy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add another variable to hold the the modified, typo-free string so we can still iterate through the original.   This new variable will be used to display text.

```
var modified_txt = "";
```

If you know the position in the string of the typo you can make an object of the position of the typos to check.

```
//Positions in the txt string where typos exist
var typos = {
  38: {},
  25: {}
}
```

As your char counter increases you can check it against the object.

```
var test = typos[char];
if (test !== undefined) {
  //Typo found do something with it
}
```

In this case I opted to write 2 new functions, 1 for adding characters and 1 for deleting them

```
function deleteCharacter(text) {
  text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
  return text;
}

function addCharacter(text, character_added) {
  text = text + character_added;
  return text;
}
```

I also decided to have one of the typo object properties be a function, so we can organize our typos and do what we want within the typo object.

```
var typos = {
  38: {
    error: 's',
    correction: function(text) {
      var temp = deleteCharacter(text);
      $('textarea').attr('placeholder', temp + '|');
      return temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can make a function call when a typo is found.

```
if (test !== undefined) {
  //Typo found do something with it
  setTimeout(function() {
    var chunk_one = test.correction(modified_txt);
    modified_txt = chunk_one;
    char++;
    typeIt();
  }, humanize());
} else { //If no typos are found then move to the next character
  setTimeout(function() {
    char++;
    typeIt();
  }, humanize());
}
```

[Full working code at codepen](http://codepen.io/cptauron/pen/xZZOqv)

Comment: Thanks @Brad, it helps me a lot.One more thing please, I want the mistake will remain firstly and complete the sentence.then the  ' | ' will come to before 's' , then delete and fadeout.

Comment: The same sort of ideas would apply if you wanted to correct the typos at the end.  Have the typo checks after the string is fully printed out then go back and add the '|' to the correct place, and delete or add characters as needed.